# Google Analytics Tracking On Sub-Folders

Tags: google-analytics

I have several blogs and I now want to host them all under the same primary domain, but I'm trying to decide on using Sub-Domains vs Sub Folders.

Due to reading recent articles I'm thinking that subfolders would be the way to go, i.e. `http://website.com/blog-1`

My problem with this is how to track individual websites using Universal Google Analytics. I found this great article/video by Rick Maggio (http://www.webgumption.com/subdomain-tracking-with-google-universal-analytics/) showing how to track subdomains, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this for sub-directories.

Comment: Since this is related to reporting, it's off topic and should be closed, but to comment, you could set up a view for each subfolder with appropriate filters applied.

Comment: @nyuen, the technical aspect would be the question of how to set the cookie path for the ga cookie, lest the cookie is set for the whole domain and not just the subfolder. That used to be possible with classic Google Analytics, but apparently not for Universal. But given the linked video that is probably not what the OP is after.

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff, I was thinking that OP was looking to track, for example, `website.com/site1`, `website.com/site2`, ... `website.com/siteN` like that, where site1, site2, siteN, are all reported on in different views all within the same property.

Comment: Yes @nyuen, I'm looking to track each site which is an extension to the primary url (`website.com/site-1`). Can you point me in the directoin of any examples of how to sey/apply a filter for this?